# Print out values in a dictionary to a new csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I have a csv file looks like this

```
year,gender,age,country
2002,F,9-10,CO
2002,F,9-10,CO
2002,M,9-10,CO
2002,F,9-10,BR
2002,M,11-15,BR
2002,F,11-15,CO
2003,F,9-10,CO
2003,M,9-10,CO
2003,F,9-10,BR
2003,M,9-10,CO
2004,F,11-15,BR
2004,F,11-15,CO
2004,F,9-10,BR
2004,F,9-10,CO
```

And I want to get a output file like this:

```
year,gender,age,country,population
2002,F,9-10,CO,2
2002,M,9-10,CO,1
2002,F,9-10,BR,1
2002,M,9-10,BR,0
2002,F,11-15,CO,1
2002,M,11-15,CO,0
2002,F,11-15,BR,0
2002,M,11-15,BR,1
2003,F,9-10,CO,1
2003,M,9-10,CO,1
2003,F,9-10,BR,1
2003,M,9-10,BR,0
2003,F,11-15,CO,0
2003,M,11-15,CO,0
2004,F,9-10,CO,1
2004,M,9-10,CO,0
2004,F,9-10,BR,1
2004,M,9-10,BR,0
2004,F,11-15,CO,1
2004,M,11-15,CO,0
2004,F,11-15,BR,1
2004,M,11-15,BR,0
```

Basically I want to print out the number of female for each year,each age and each country, so year,gender,age and country will be the key of the dictionary. Moreover, some year do not have the data of a specific country or some year do not have a specific age for a specific country. For example, year 2003,female do not have data for 11-15 age group in country CO. In this situation, the population will be 0. Moreover, some year do not have a specific gender data at all. For example, for year 2004, there is no male data for all the age and country, but I still want to print it out in the output file with population 0.

Below are some python code I wrote but it doesn't work and I don't know how to deal with the missing data and print it out as 0 in the population field.

```
import csv
import os
import sys
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter
import math
from collections import Counter

# Create dictionary to hold the data
valDic = {}

# Read data into dictionary
with open(sys.argv[1], "r",) as inputfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter = ',')    
    next(readcsv)
    for line in readcsv:
        key = line[0] + line[1] + line[2] + line[3]
        year = line[0]
        gender = line[1]
        age = line[2]
        country = line[3]
        if key in valDic:
            key = key + 1
        else:
            valDic[key] = [year, gender, age, country, 0] # 0s are placeholder for running sum and itemCount
    inputfile.close()  

newcsvfile = []

for key in valDic:
    newcsvfile.append([valDic[key][0], valDic[key][1], valDic[key][2], valDic[key][3], len(valDic[key])])

newcsvfile = sorted(newcsvfile)
newcsvfile = [["year", "gender", "age", "country", "population"]] 

with open(sys.argv[2], "w") as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
    writer.writerows(newcsvfile)
```

Comment: using `df.groupby(['year', 'genter', 'age', 'country'])` you could count it

Comment: you could at start create dictionary with all keys and values 0. If some key doesn't exists in csv then you will have 0 in dictionary.

Comment: @furas can you be more specific how to do that? In the real file there are more than 2 countries and ages and I can't list them all. I'm new to coding so I don't know how to create a dic with all keys as you said

Comment: to get 0 for missing values you would have to first create lists with all countries, all age ranges. Using these list you can check if you have missing data in dictionary after filling dictionary. OR at start you can create dictionary with all items filled by zero and then add values from csv. SO you would have to first read csv only to get all coutries and all age ranges, and later read csv again to create dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can store each combination of year, gender, age, country as a tuple and use this as the key for your dictionary. We also maintain a unique set of each of these values. We iterate over every combination we have seen, and if the data doesn't exist for that (like in 2004 only female exists but not male); then we can add '0' for this.

Demo:

```py
import csv
import sys

# Create dictionary to hold the data
valDic = {}

years, genders, age, country = set(), set(), set(), set()

# Read data into dictionary
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r',) as inputfile:

    reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:

        key = (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])

        years.add(key[0])
        genders.add(key[1])
        age.add(key[2])
        country.add(key[3])

        if key not in valDic:
            valDic[key]=0

        valDic[key]+=1


#Add missing combinations
for y in years:
    for g in genders:
        for a in age:
            for c in country:
                key = (y, g, a, c)
                if key not in valDic:
                    valDic[key]=0

#Prepare new CSV
newcsvfile = [["year", "gender", "age", "country", "population"]] 

for key, val in sorted(valDic.items()):
    newcsvfile.append([key[0], key[1], key[2], key[3], valDic[key]])

with open(sys.argv[2], "w", newline='') as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
    writer.writerows(newcsvfile)
```

Outputs:

```
year,gender,age,country,population
2002,F,11-15,BR,0
2002,F,11-15,CO,1
2002,F,9-10,BR,1
2002,F,9-10,CO,2
2002,M,11-15,BR,1
2002,M,11-15,CO,0
2002,M,9-10,BR,0
2002,M,9-10,CO,1
2003,F,11-15,BR,0
2003,F,11-15,CO,0
2003,F,9-10,BR,1
2003,F,9-10,CO,1
2003,M,11-15,BR,0
2003,M,11-15,CO,0
2003,M,9-10,BR,0
2003,M,9-10,CO,2
2004,F,11-15,BR,1
2004,F,11-15,CO,1
2004,F,9-10,BR,1
2004,F,9-10,CO,1
2004,M,11-15,BR,0
2004,M,11-15,CO,0
2004,M,9-10,BR,0
2004,M,9-10,CO,0
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `pandas` for this.

I can read all and create `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])
```

Using `groupby` I can group rows and count them to get `population` for existing data. It creates list of list with columns in different order but later I will convert it to new `DataFrame` to change columns order and sort rows.

```
groups = df.groupby(['year', 'age', 'country', 'gender'])

data = []

for index, group in groups:
    data.append([*index, len(group)]) # create row with population
```

Usign `.unique()` I can get all unique values in columns.

```
unique_years     = df['year'].unique()
unique_genders   = df['gender'].unique()
unique_age       = df['age'].unique()
unique_countries = df['country'].unique()
```

I use them with `itertools.product` to create all possible combinations of year, gender, age, country to check which combination is missing in data to add it with `0`

existing combinations I can find previouse `groups.indices`

```
import itertools

all_indices = groups.indices

for index in itertools.product(all_years, all_age, all_countries, all_genders):
    if index not in indices:
        data.append([*index, 0]) # add missing row
```

After that I have all data and I can convert to `DataFrame` to change columns order and sort rows

```
# create DataFrame with new values
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'age', 'country', 'gender',  'population'])

# change columns order
final_df = final_df[['year', 'gender', 'age', 'country', 'population']]

# sort by 
final_df = final_df.sort_values(['year', 'age', 'country', 'gender'], ascending=[True, False, False, True])
```

Finally I can save it in new csv

```
final_df.to_csv(sys.argv[2], index=False)
```

---

Full working example - instead of reading from file I use `io.StringIO` to simulate file in memory - so everyone can copy it and test it without your full data.

```
text = '''year,gender,age,country
2002,F,9-10,CO
2002,F,9-10,CO
2002,M,9-10,CO
2002,F,9-10,BR
2002,M,11-15,BR
2002,F,11-15,CO
2003,F,9-10,CO
2003,M,9-10,CO
2003,F,9-10,BR
2003,M,9-10,CO
2004,F,11-15,BR
2004,F,11-15,CO
2004,F,9-10,BR
2004,F,9-10,CO'''

#---------------------------------------

import pandas as pd

#df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])

import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))

print(df)

#---------------------------------------

groups = df.groupby(['year', 'age', 'country', 'gender'])

data = []

for index, group in groups:
    data.append([*index, len(group)])

#---------------------------------------

unique_years     = df['year'].unique()
unique_genders   = df['gender'].unique()
unique_age       = df['age'].unique()
unique_countries = df['country'].unique()

#print('years    :', unique_years)
#print('genders  :', unique_genders)
#print('age      :', unique_age)
#print('countries:', unique_countries)

import itertools

all_indices = groups.indices

for index in itertools.product(all_years, all_age, all_countries, all_genders):
    if index not in indices:
        data.append([*index, 0])

#---------------------------------------

# create DataFrame with new values
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'age', 'country', 'gender',  'population'])

# change columns order
final_df = final_df[['year', 'gender', 'age', 'country', 'population']]

# sort by 
final_df = final_df.sort_values(['year', 'age', 'country', 'gender'], ascending=[True, False, False, True])

# reset index
final_df = final_df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(final_df)

# save in file
#final_df.to_csv(sys.argv[2], index=False)
final_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```